# Django 3: Unable to generate dynamic object view

Tags: python, django

I have successfully created the expected structure for my model and in the error variables I can see that the DB object was returned but I am not able to resolve the page. I am getting error " TypeError at /ticket-edit/2 - **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance' "  - am I referencing the object incorrectly? I want to use the existing TicketForm but populate the result with the field values from the URL.

In the error the local var shows that the expected ticket was retrieved:

```
Variable: Value
```

- aTicketID:   '2'
- context:     {}
- obj:         <Ticket: 2
  2021-10-06 Ticket Title Ticket Desc> request
- <WSGIRequest: GET '/ticket-edit/2'>
- Exception Location:  /views.py, line 118, in ticket_edit
- line 118 is: updateform=TicketForm(instance=obj)

Urls.py (I use URL instead of path to generate the ID link)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ticket-edit/(?P<aTicketID>\d+)', views.ticket_edit, name='ticket-edit')
]
```

Models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    #---Base Meta-----------------------------------------
    appTicketID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField(
        max_length=20,
        auto_now_add=True)
    issue_title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    issue_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.appTicketID} "
                f"{self.date_submitted} "
                f"{self.issue_title} "
                f"{self.issue_description} "

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('ticket-edit', kwargs={'aTicketID': self.appTicketID}
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def ticket_edit(request, aTicketID):
    context = {}
    obj=Ticket.objects.get(appTicketID=aTicketID)
    updateform=TicketForm(instance=obj)
    
    if aTicketID == None:
        aTicketID = 1
    aticket = Ticket.objects.filter(appTicketID=aTicketID)
    print('\n-----------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('TicketFiltered: ', aticket)
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------\n')
    
    context = {
        "has_error": False,
        "updateform": updateform,
        "aticket": aticket
    }
    return render(request,'appname/ticket-edit.html', context)
```

Tried this but results in error: 'Ticket' object has no attribute 'get'

```
obj = Ticket.objects.get(appTicketID=aTicketID)
updateform = TicketForm(obj)
```

Comment: Have you tried `updateform = TicketForm(instance=obj)`?

Comment: Where is `TicketForm` defined? Extends from `forms.Form` or `forms.ModelForm`?

Comment: @JoseAntonioCastroCastro from forms.Form

Comment: @BCerveza, the `instance` argument is only for `ModelForm` instances. You need use `initial`as dictionary in this form: [Django docs about](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values)

Comment: @JoseAntonioCastroCastro Thanks much! That is what I ended up doing - its all working now.